# Customize the Wordpress Woocommerce billing address edit forms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By default, Woocommerce has two types of addresses which are **Billing and Delivery address**, and these informations can be edited from **My Account** page, you click the "edit" link, form opens in a new window.

But this is what, I want the account page to look like:

When the user visits the My Account page, I would like to have both [the billing (facturacion) and shipping address (datos envio)] edit forms there on the same page. How can I achieve this?

[image]

I want to have both forms in the same page instead in two different ones.

I have been trying to "separate" both forms and have them one next to the other in the same page instead of having them in two different page/instances.

The file form-edit-address contains the forms.

**This is what I have tried:**

in the begining of the code it reads

```
$page_title = ( $load_address === 'billing' ) ? __( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' );
```

I removed the shipping bit. but breaks all.
clearly here is where i have to chop a bit to render billing or shipping forms, my experience is limited with php so I have been trying all sorts of combinations like walking blind. Can somebody help me understand this code to customize it?

**This is the untouched code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit address form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce, $current_user;

$page_title = ( $load_address === 'billing' ) ? __( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' );

get_currentuserinfo();
?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<?php if ( ! $load_address ) : ?>

    <?php wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-address.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <form method="post">

        <h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title ); ?></h3>

        <?php foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, ! empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST[ $key ] ) : $field['value'] ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="button big" name="save_address" value="<?php _e( 'Save Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address' ); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
        </p>

    </form>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
<?php
// get the user meta
$userMeta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id());

// get the form fields
$countries = new WC_Countries();
$billing_fields = $countries->get_address_fields( '', 'billing_' );
$shipping_fields = $countries->get_address_fields( '', 'shipping_' );
?>

<!-- billing form -->
<?php
$load_address = 'billing';
$page_title   = __( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' );
?>
<form action="/my-account/edit-address/billing/" class="edit-account" method="post">

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title ); ?></h2>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <?php foreach ( $billing_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $userMeta[$key][0] ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_address" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
    </p>

</form>

<!-- shipping form -->
<?php
$load_address = 'shipping';
$page_title   = __( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' );
?>
<form action="/my-account/edit-address/shipping/" class="edit-account" method="post">

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title ); ?></h2>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <?php foreach ( $shipping_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $userMeta[$key][0] ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_address" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
    </p>

</form>
```