# Woocommerce - Remove fields from woocommerce_form_field including validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter

I am trying to customise the Woocommerce myaccount page, in particular the edit address page.

I want to display both the shipping + billing address forms on a single page. Ideally, in a single form with a one save button.  I also need to remove a lot of the fields, so that it's a much simpler form of just an address (no name, company, etc).

I have implemented the code found on [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37286898/2115227). It works nicely in that it shows both forms.  However, I cannot remove the fields from the forms.  If I try code like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'custom_override_shipping_fields' );


function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['billing_email']);
  return $fields;
}

function custom_override_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['shipping_company']);
    unset($fields['shipping_first_name']);
    unset($fields['shipping_last_name']);
  return $fields;
}
```

It doesn't work, the fields are no longer shown but the form does not save on click... it just redirects to /my-account/edit-address/billing/ - and doesn't save. (the same form shown on this page doesn't save either).

I've also tried:

```
foreach ( $billing_fields as $key => $field ) :
   if($key != 'billing_first_name' && $key != 'billing_last_name') :
      woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $userMeta[$key][0] );
   endif;
endforeach;
```

This removes the field from displaying, BUT the validation still exists - and any filter code I add to functions using
`woocommerce_checkout_fields` to remove the validation doesn't seem to affect this form at all.

Is there a way to either:

1. Remove fields from this form generated by woocommerce_form_field including the validation?
2. Create a custom form that allows me to set the input fields manually in the code, and update any fields that are there, ignoring the validation from Woocommerce completely?

Answer (score 1):

This should work 100%. You need to state whether the fields you are removing is from billing or shipping and this is done by adding the ['billing'] or ['shipping'], whichever it is.

After this, adding the function directly to woocommerce_checkout_fields will apply both for billing and shipping.

For phone and company fields you can disable it in admin panel itself, do it.

**Edit:** And yes, all validation that was involved with the fields in the past will be removed. You can then apply any validation you need.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'brandimagemarketer_remove_billing_fields_checkout' );
 
function brandimagemarketer_remove_billing_fields_checkout( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
 unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);

  unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
  unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']);
 unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']);
unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_email']);

  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but please re-read the original post.  The fields are being displayed on a custom myaccount address page, as per this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37286898/2115227. - Your code does not remove the fields from this code.  The code I added in the original post removes the fields, but doesn't save.

Comment: To confirm,  the forms are being 'built' by:  <?php foreach ( $billing_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $userMeta[$key][0] ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Hi, Alright got it. I tested your code and it works fine for me, the fields are removed and validations also are removed and upon submit the form are saved without any error notice both in myaccount page and checkout page.

There might be conflicts from your custom codes or plugins. Try commenting your custom codes or disabling plugins and see if anything changes.

Comment: I tried in a brand new Wordpress install, running the TwentyTwentyOne theme, NO plugins other than Woocommerce, NO custom code other than the two add_filter codes in my Original post... and it didn't save to the Database.  On save it looked like it saved the addresses, but then when I navigated out and went back into the address it wasn't saved

Comment: It seems that it doesn't save when I exclude billing_country.  When I remove billing_country, it saves